# Is "He is 7-year-old" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure if this sentence is grammatically correct. Is "He is 7-year-old" grammatically correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"7-year-old" is used as a compound adjective.

"*Hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a compound adjective.*"

[GrammarBook](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp)

If we include the indefinite article "*a*", this means that "*He is a seven-year-old boy.*" would be correct. This is often shortened to "*He is a seven-year-old*", in which "*boy*" is omitted, treating the compound adjective as a noun that stands for the noun phrase "*seven-year-old boy*".

It might be argued that a compound adjective could be used in the same way as the adjective *intelligent* in the grammatical sentence "*He is intelligent*". But, perhaps because there is no implied noun phrase in "*He is seven-year-old*", or because the compound adjective describes his state rather than his nature, many would regard it as ungrammatical to do so and would prefer to say simply "*He is seven years old*".

I can think of a similar construction "*He is run-of-the-mill*" (meaning that he is ordinary) in which the compound adjective acts successfully as a noun because it describes the nature of the person rather his state.

There will be controversy about this. Perhaps it is a question of usage rather than of rigid rules?

Comment: It is regarding the application of the rules with stringent fidelity.

Answer (score 2):

"7-year-old" is a noun (or noun phrase) and therefore requires an article.

> He is a 7-year old.

Alternatively "7 years old" is an adjectival phrase which doesn't take an article.

> He is 7 years old.

Comment: "He is a 7-year-old boy" — Isn't "7-year-old" an adjectival phrase?

Comment: Yes indeed it is. This question goes deeper than I first thought.

Comment: Isn't "7 years old" an _adverbial_ phrase modifying 'is' or is that just me? After all in answers the question 'he is what?'

Comment: @BoldBen no. The verb _to be_ takes a predicate noun or predicate adjective instead of an object (they are teachers; they are competent).  These are no more adverbial than is the object "carrots" in the sentence "she likes carrots."  This is true even though "carrots" answers the question "she likes what?"  If it were truly adverbial, we would say "those teachers are competently," which is just bizarre.

Comment: @Cognoscenti sometimes seven-year-old functions as an adjective phrase.  Sometimes it functions as a noun phrase.  Apparently Roman grammarians didn't even distinguish between adjectives and nouns.

Comment: @phoog How can I differentiate between them? If there is an object next to "seven-year-old" (and/or an article before it), it will be adjective phrase, am I right?

Comment: *7-yearold* is an adjective which can occur either as a modifier as in *a seven-year old boy* or as a modifier-head of an NP: *a 7-year old*, somewhat similarly to *the blind*. In other words, you can have an adjective phrase head an NP with an ellipted noun.